# what are the important considerations when using /robots.txt & /sitemap.xml files

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016

is /robots.txt & /sitemap.xml files will be security vulnerabilities for SharePoint Sites?

what are the important considerations when using /robots.txt:

can i remove /robots.txt,/sitemap.xml file from root directory of web application for internet facing sites for save web site from malware robots that scan the web for security vulnerabilities.

what happen when i remove /sitemap.xml file for web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files will not cause security issues as they need manually provision in a SharePoint farm. Removing these files will have no influence on your farm.

You can refer to an article here for introduction: [Sitemaps in SharePoint 2013.](https://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/sitemaps-in-sharepoint-2013/)

> Sitemaps basically inform the search engines about the pages and their
> metadata, present in your site. This help the crawlers in picking up
> those pages. This is a great feature especially for public facing
> websites.

Comment: Hi Chelsea please can you share any reference from Microsoft that said no security issues ?